# Helmholtz-Hodge decomposition theorem in the fast fluid dynamics simulation

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am reading the [Fast Fluid Dynamics Simulation on the GPU](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/books/HTML/gpugems/gpugems_ch38.html) article and stuck with the following part:

*We can use the Helmholtz-Hodge Decomposition Theorem to define a projection operator, p.jpg , that projects a vector field w onto its divergence-free component, u. If we apply p.jpg to Equation 7, we get:*

[image]

Could you please help me understand how we can derive this equation with the Helmholtz-Hodge Decomposition Theorem here and what is the physical interpretation in the context of this article this formula has?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to spell out the explanation in detail, but this idea is  sketched out in the exercise 6.7 on page 228 of our book:

https://goldbart.gatech.edu/PostScript/MS_PG_book/bookmaster.pdf

Comment: Thank you, but this is more a task to solve rather than the explanation. It brings to live other questions directed to use Helmholtz-Hodge Decomposition Theorem, but doesn't help me understand my case. I have even more information here: [Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition), but is still hard for me to catch how this leads to the formula above and especially what is the physical interpretation of this.

Comment: The basic idea is that the pressure does not dictate the motion of the fluid, but is instead a constraint which is dictated by the motion.  The HH decomposition makes this clear.